# Listing classpath throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, classpath

I have used following code to print the classpath from inside of jar (build with intelliJ):

```
    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).getURLs();
    for (URL url : urls) {
        System.out.println(url);
    }
```

However this throws NullPointerException. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *What* throws a `NullPointerException`? Specifically?

Comment: @Reimeus but what in this code would throw an NPE?

Comment: @AndyTurner I assume `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` : _The system `ClassLoader` for delegation, or `null` if none_.

Comment: @Sotirios huh. I'd assumed there would always be a system class loader. TIL.